# Error while adding a wcf service refrence in ASP.Net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, wcf

I get this message error from visual studio when I attempt to add a service reference in visual studio using an url address.

> There was an error downloading
>   'http://serviceendpoint.com/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata'. Unable
>   to connect to the remote server No connection could be made because
>   the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8888 Metadata
>   contains a reference that cannot be resolved:
>   'http://serviceendpoint.com.tn:10200/'. There was no endpoint
>   listening at http://serviceendpoint.com.tn:10200/ that could accept
>   the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP
>   action. See InnerException, if present, for more details. Unable to
>   connect to the remote server No connection could be made because the
>   target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8888 If the service is
>   defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding
>   the service reference again.

However, this url is accessible from the browser and from another computer using visual studio.

Comment: Can you check your host file? Seems like it doesn't contain reference to your localhost

Comment: Glad I could help!!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check your host file? Seems like it doesn't contain reference to your localhost

Comment: Added as an answer just in case needed by someone in future!